# Piping List Command to Chflags command in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Crew super novice question here:

While using terminal on mac, I want to make all the files in a folder hidden. I know I can make a single file or folder hidden by using

```
chflags hidden my/path/name
```

but I want to make each individual file in that folder hidden I tried piping `ls` into it to no avail. My ideas have been to use

```
chflags hidden | ls

chflags hidden > ls

ls > chflags hidden
```

and I have even tried

```
chflags hidden /my/path/name/*
```

but none of that seems to be working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`chflags hidden /my/path/name/*` should work, provided the path is correct. Try `ls /my/path/name`, and see what it shows. You may be running into trouble because of the presence/lack of a "/" at the front of the path. If it's there, it means the path starts at the top level ("root") of your startup volume. If it's not there, it means the path starts in your current working directory.

As for the others: a pipe takes the output from one command (i.e. what it would normally print to the terminal), and sends it to the input of another command. `chflags` doesn't print anything except errors (and those don't go via the pipe), and `ls` doesn't read input (it does take command-line arguments, but those are different).

Also, "|" is used to pipe between commands (what I just described). ">" does something different: it sends output to a file. From your tests, you'll now have (empty) files named "ls" and "chflags".